# Maven2 to Maven3 Migration java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: maven, hudson

I am trying to update to M3 but I have a few issues/LOTS to work out. I am stuck on one particular failure.

```
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```

That causes a stack overflow and then

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:166)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:161)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:112)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:91)
    at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:130)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:544)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:252)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:476)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.PrintStreamLogger.info(PrintStreamLogger.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.logging.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)...about1000 more
```

What is going on...?

Comment: This issue is caused by **maven-assembly-plugin**

Answer (score 13):

Updating maven assembly plugin to latest version fixed my problem.

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
```

Comment: This also fix my problem in Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

Workaround, not a fix:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xss2m
```

What fixed it for me : Make sure you specify a version for maven assembly plugin and make sure it's updated.

```
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows it is a StackOverflow error, try to increase stack size to 5MB or more by adding -Xss5M in VM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This failure log is from running in Hudson. Can you make sure it works on the command line first. That will make it much easier. Also if you want to run on Hudson I would suggest to make sure you use the new Maven 3 integration that allows you to do Maven 3 build steps in a free-style project and NOT use the Maven2/3 project type, since it has been declared legacy.

Comment: Samething when I build from CMD  at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)  It fills the buffer so that why I had the above results. I do not know if its a version thing or something to do with the BAT file that runs when it builds the Hibernate mapping files?

Comment: Well... try to remove one plugin after the other from the build to figure out where the problem is then.

Comment: @Twitch.  At what point do you get this error when running from cmd?  You may want to post relevant pom snippet and log around it.